# How can I show a Bootstrap row on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, html5-canvas

I want to show my bootstrap modal row in the middle when click on mobile:

Below is a desktop view which is perfect:

[image: View is perfect on desktop, One row divide in two i:e cover all width 50%-50%]

Below is a Mobile browser view which is not good (I want same just like desktop view one row 50%-50% width):

[image: I want this view just like it is showing on desktop browser]

Here is my Bootstrap code code:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row containerSD">

        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:white">
            <input type="radio" name="price_sort" value="low"> Low to High<br>
            <input type="radio" name="price_sort" value="high"> High to Low<br><br>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:white">
            <input type="text" name="min_price" class="price-range"  placeholder="Min $" value=""> To
            <input type="text" name="max_price" class="price-range"  placeholder="Max $" value=""> <br><br>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Any idea or suggestions would be welcome.

Comment: What have you tried? You'll need to write some JavaScript. Please show your effort and ask a more specific question about your code.

Comment: I strongly suspect the difference is simply the modal width, since you're using `col-md-6`. If the modal on mobile is below the `md` breakpoint width, then it will default to the stacked view rather than the side-by-side.

Comment: Have you tried `col-6`, without the `md` breakpoint?